# Is lack of space after punctuation caused by software or geography or something else?

Tags: discussion

> Paris is in France.London is in England.If Paris is in France,then London is in England.

A lack of space before continuing after a comma or a period is something I have rarely seen except when it's an inadvertent typo, except on math.stackexchange.com.  If it occurs 30 times in one posting without a single instance of what I was brought up to consider the standard form, that's not a typo.  If I look at 30 posted questions and eight of them follow that form, and if that happens every day for several years (and it has) then I wonder what's going on.  Two guesses:

- Some people use software to create MathJax code rather than doing it by hand, and it often writes code that looks like something a psychotic would write.  Might it be that that same software is doing this?
- Is there some country (e.g. maybe India?) where this is standard and where many of those who post here live?

Comment: The punctuation's rule in France is to make a space between the word and these marks ? ! : so for example in your question they write (in France) (e.g. maybe India ?) I think that every country has its rules.

Comment: I have a friend from India who said that he didn't know there were meant to be spaces after punctuation marks. Also my phone doesn't put spaces, so I will say it very well could be a combination of both factors.

Answer (score 5):

I have also seen posts spaced like this:

> Paris is in France . London is in England.If Paris is in France ,then London is in England

Thus, I would not discard the possibility it is just a combination of carelessness, ignorance of the rules, and lack of appreciation for the relevance to get this right.

However, I do appreciate the fact that for somebody native in a language that is quite different from English (non-Latin alphabet, etc.) this might be harder, than for those native in English or at least in a language using the Latin alphabet.

While it is the case that even different languages using the Latin alphabet have slightly different rules (an example is given in the comments), I would not know of a classical rule where no space is  to be used after a full-stop, neither does the Wikpedia page on [the punctuation "space" given one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29).

Except there one can find the following quote:

> According to Lynne Truss, "young people" today using digital media "are now accustomed to following a full stop with a lower-case letter and no space".

I take this as further evidence for the possibility mentioned above.

Comment: "If it's that wrong, why didn't autocorrect stop me?" Or, more likely: "muh autocorrect".

Comment: Well that last quote is from 2004, back in the days where you had to type out your whole SMS yourself. Nowadays autocorrect adds the space after the dot automatically.

Comment: So... you're saying that we should be grateful for "London" and "Paris" instead of "london" and "paris"?

Comment: @Asaf what pairs are you longing for?

Comment: The ones I ordered.

Comment: @Asaf sorry, ordered pairs are out.

Comment: I can still long for them. I have  few freedoms left, dammit!

Comment: I have a friend from India who said that he didn't know there were meant to be spaces after punctuation marks. Also my phone doesn't put spaces, so I will say it very well could be a combination of both factors.

Comment: @OceansBleed that's interesting. But from my experience corresponding with a fair number of mathematicians from and/or in India, I can assure you that this  is not at all universal.